# Is this a proper CakePHP inner join using find?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

This is what I want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM `potential_matches` INNER JOIN release ON release.asin = potential_matches.asin WHERE release.id = 6;
```

This is what i have so far:

```
class Release extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasMany = array('PotentialMatch');
}

class PotentialMatch extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo = array('Release');
}


$this->Release->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('PotentialMatch')
    'conditions' => array(
        'Message.to' => 6
    )
));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If don't pass it the `type` value it will use LEFT JOIN by default. See this [link](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/07/17/left-join-vs-inner-join/)